# Why is my user object not accepting a change in one of its fields in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to change both the user currently running the `select_prayer_partner` method, to make its `prayer_partner_id` equal to the partner's `id`. And also, for the partner's `prayer_partner_id` to be equal to the current user's `id`.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

# a bunch of code here

  def select_prayer_partner
    partner = User.where("denomination not in(?)", [self.denomination])
                  .where("location not LIKE ?", [self.location.split(",")[1].strip])
                  .where("prayer_partner_id IS NULL").sample
    self.prayer_partner_id = partner.id
    partner.prayer_partner_id = self.id
  end

end
```

In rails console, I find that the `self.prayer_partner_id = partner.id` works just fine, the prayer partner id is successfully changed to the partner id given by the SQL query requiring a different denomination and a different state or country, and who has no current prayer partner. Unfortunately, `partner.prayer_partner_id = self.id` does not work - the other user's `prayer_partner_id` remains `nil`. Any ideas what could be going on here?

Comment: i assume after this method  `.save` method runs for the self user object so that user will get updated. If you also want to partner to be updated as well you need to call `partner.save` manually. Because `.save` method calling for the `self` not for the `partner`. Also you said it works in rails conlose. If you are also not calling `.save` method for the self user than self user also will not be updated in database.

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually thought about calling .save but I forgot to reload rails console with the changes, d'oh! But this time it worked and I got a successful UPDATE call on the database, changing the partner's ppid.

Comment: i'm glad that i could help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered, with help from Mehmet Adil Istikbal, that I needed to call `.save` on my `partner` object to save the changes to the database. Now everything works properly.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

# a bunch of code here

  def select_prayer_partner
    partner = User.where("denomination not in(?)", [self.denomination])
                  .where("location not LIKE ?", [self.location.split(",")[1].strip])
                  .where("prayer_partner_id IS NULL").sample
    self.prayer_partner_id = partner.id
    partner.prayer_partner_id = self.id

    partner.save #this is what I forgot to do - save the partner 

  end

end
```